# What is MS App Insights throughput?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am trying to figure out if App Insights is good solution for my app tracing. I cannot find any capacity numbers. Is there something published? How many logs per second it can take per one application or box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#limits) as of 2018-10-01:

- Total data per day:   100 GB
- Throttling:   32 K events/second
- Data retention:   90 days
- Availability multi-step test detailed results retention:  90 days
- Maximum event size:   64 K
- Property and metric name length:  150
- Property value string length: 8,192
- Trace and exception message length:   10 K
- Availability tests count per app: 100
- Profiler data retention:  5 days
- Profiler data sent per day:   10 GB

For more detailed break-down also have a look at the [Azure Monitor Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/monitor/) page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the short summary of [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#limits) as of 4/17/2017:

- Total data per day: 500 GB
- Free data per month: 1GB
- Throttling: 32 k events/second
- Data retention: 90 days
- Maximum event size: 64 K

However, currently the throttling limit seems to be temporary lowered to 12 K events/second as per [this AI service blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/2017/03/31/application-insights-advisory-0331/).

P.S. [Application Insights Pricing page](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing#limits-summary) also has the similar table with the limits. This may be a better reference for the future changes if any.